# Comparing data in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am indexing user data for each day and using Kibana to analyse it, so far I am able to visualize all my requirement. But I am not able to visualize following use case

```
I want to analyse total number of user,repeated number of users from previous day and how many are unique.
```

I can visualize **total number of user for day** , but how do I compare today's data from yesterday.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: please show ,What you have tired

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your requirement correctly, but you could create a Vertical Bar Chart visualization with Kibana and change the default 'Count' to 'Unique Count', select the field you like to do the unique count for and then add an X-Axis with a date histogram on your timestamp field.

This will create a bar chart and each bar will contain the unique count for each time interval. So if you select 7 days as your timeframe and 1 day interval in your X-Axis date histogram, you'll see the unique count per day.

Comment: But this will give me **unique user/day**, but I want to know how many of them already visited, kind of this subquery  `select unique(userid) from user where  date={today} and userid not in (select unique(userid) from user where date={yesterday})`

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of funnel, not sure if you can do that in ES.